# Installing on an existent Windows partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I wanted to install Ubuntu on a dual boot system. Main OS is Windows Vista on drive C. I have another partition called "I" where I had installed Windows 7 but now I have formatted it. I also have a recovery partition called "E", a second internal HD called "D" that I use for data, and two external HDs (both for data). I have made a DVD with Ubuntu 14.04 and I easily go through the early stages of booting the system from the DVD, but when the Ubuntu installer asks me where (in which partition) i want it I cannot identify which one is I. Any advice? Also, I need to know if there's something specific I should do to ensure dual boot.

Thanks a lot,

Roberto

Comment: I will then be something like /dev/sdaX, try to find an empty partition. Also, if you know the size, you can identify I:\ much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

1. Boot to Windows Vista and look for the size of `I:` (take a photo if need be).
2. Now, boot with Ubuntu DVD and compare the size of partitions with the size of `I:`. Now, the size that matches the partition from before is your `I:` drive.

Even if the size matches with more than one partition, don't worry and check for the partition that has most free space as because you have just recently formatted `I:`.

Also, you can easily dual-boot with Windows 7, no need to do anything special.